# Ventana que tome la forma de una imágen en Gtk3

Tags: python, gtk, ventana

El problema que tengo es que no encuentro la forma de que una ventana
en Gtk3 tome la forma de una imágen que le proporcione. Tengo la forma de realizarlo
en gtk2, pero estoy trasladando todo el código a la versión más nueva de la
libreria. Este es una parte del código que tengo hecho hecho en Python:

```
pixbuf = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_file(path_to_file)
pixmap, mask = pixbuf.render_pixmap_and_mask()
window.image.set_from_pixmap(pixmap, mask)
window.image.show()
window.fixed.set_size_request(100, 100)
window.fixed.show()

# Este método funciona para que el widget(la ventana)
# tome la forma de la imagen
window.shape_combine_mask(mask, 0, 0)
```

Estuve analizando varias páginas, pero sin resultados.
Encontré este pero no me sirvió mucho:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/97789/creating-a-gtk-window-with-input-shape-mask-in-python

Saludos y espero que puedan ayudarme.